# How to know a JavaScript function accepts a simple parameter or a destructured object?

Tags: javascript, callback, jsx

Consider these two functions:

```
const render = (entity) => {
   // function body
}

const render = ({
    entity,
    isAdmin
}) => {
   // function body
}
```

Now let's say I want to call this function. And if it's accepting a destructured object, I should pass the arguments differently.

```
render({
    name: 'John', 
    age: 40
})

// or

render({
    entity: {
      name: 'John',
      age: 40
    },
    isAdmin: true
})
```

Is there a way for me to know if a function accepts destructured object as its parameter?

Please note that `render.length` returns 1 for both of these functions. And `arguments` does not help me because it's accessible **inside** the function, not outside it.

**Update**.

This is the real scenario.

We have an administration panel (similar to React Admin) that is used by over than 500 projects across many companies. You can imagine that we have thousands of lists to be shown in tabular format.

Now, for each table, developers give us a `render` function which is a React component to be used for each row of the table.

This is how they use our `<List />` component:

```
const Customers = () => {
    return <List
        // other props like title, headers, etc.
        row={entity => <>
             <td>{entity.name}</td>
        </>}
    />
}
```

We don't want to force them across thousands of lists to write `row={({entity, metadata}) => <><td>{entity.name}</td></>}`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250214/discussion-on-question-by-big-boy-how-to-know-a-javascript-function-accepts-a-si).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me why you would need to do this. The parameters to a function don't and can't change once declared, and you should always know what parameters a function accepts before calling it.

However, just for the sake of it, here's an example of a way you could do it. Stringify the function, then use a regex to match the `({ })` in the parameter list.

```js
const render1 = (entity) => {}

const render2 = ({
    entity,
    isAdmin
}) => {}

const render3 = (arg) => someotherFunc({arg})

function doesDestructure(func){
  return /\({.+}\) =>/gm.test(func.toString().replaceAll("\n", ""))
}

console.log(doesDestructure(render1))
console.log(doesDestructure(render2))
console.log(doesDestructure(render3))
```

Or a version that will work for all functions:

```js
const render1 = (entity) => {}

const render2 = ({
    entity,
    isAdmin
}) => {}

const render3 = (entity) => subscribe(({entity}) => {  })

function doesDestructure(func){
  return /\({.+}\)/gm.test(func.toString().replaceAll("\n", "").split("=>")[0])
}

console.log(doesDestructure(render1))
console.log(doesDestructure(render2))
console.log(doesDestructure(render3))
```

Comment: Won't this entirely depend on whether or not the function is formatted nicely? It would fail on `(arg) => someotherFunc({arg})`

Comment: @Phil I noticed that too. I updated the regex.

Comment: @Spectric Then you probably should have added that as `render3` in your example

Comment: @RuanMendes Good call :)

Comment: Even if it's really unclear that this is actually going to do any good. Feels like it's going to harm some codebase .

Comment: Consider `const fn1 = (entity) => subscribe(({entity}) => { ... })`. I think this is an impossible task

Comment: @Spectric, in many other languages, we have the concept of function overloading. There are multiple versions of a function that you can call.

Comment: @Bigboy But why don't you know ahead of time which version you need to call? If it's overloaded, you can call either. jQuery did a lot fo that. It's not up to the caller to sort that out usually. What sort of dynamic programming is going on there?

Comment: @Phil looks like it's time to bring out the big gun: `split`

Comment: @RuanMendes, it's not harming the codebase at all. It's a dynamic table that needs to render its rows and needs to pass the data, or data + metadata to the row based on the requester.

Comment: @Bigboy I still don't understand why the caller is concerned with what to pass in. The render function has to implement the logic of checking what was passed in. Sorry but your problem is not clear.

Comment: @Bigboy yes, it seems like whatever functionality that might require a function to be overriden can be implemented inside the function. Having to check the func from the caller is an expensive task.

Comment: @RuanMendes, yes you're right. The **correct** way is for render functions to check what was passed in. But that results in hundreds of lines of boilerplate code. When we can check it in one centralized place, we choose the second option for the sake of code clarity in hundreds of other places.

Comment: @RuanMendes, we have one dynamic data table source, but hundreds of tables for different lists. We prefer to do it in our dynamic table, than to do it in every other table.

Comment: @Bigboy You can massage the parameters in the same way from all functions. There are different ways to do that but what you are suggesting is surely going to make other developers hate you in the future  Every caller would have to check, I really can't follow you.

Comment: @Bigboy It's a really bad idea to look for destructuring syntax in the function parameter declaration. Changing the code of a function from `(obj) => console.log(obj.a, obj.b)` to `({a, b}) => console.log(a, b)` must stay an implementation detail, it is expected to do exactly the same thing and must not break the caller! You're seriously considering to write such fragile code? Sure you can do that when fiddling around and prototyping, but absolutely don't use it in production with hundredths of library users!

Answer (score 2):

Your original question was definitely an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) but now that you've cleared it up, I believe the issue is...

1. You have a shared component (probably React) that accepts a function property used to allow callers to dictate how a part of the result is rendered (ie table rows). That function looks something like this currently (Typescript syntax for clarity)

   ```ts
   row: (entity: Entity) => JSX.Element
   ```
2. You want to introduce a new element to the renderer including some meta-data but you want to use an object (as opposed to multiple args) to avoid

   1. Locked in parameter order
   2. Locked in number of parameters

   ```ts
   row: (obj: MetaData & { entity: Entity }) => JSX.Element
   ```

To save the sanity of your developers, I would recommend introducing a new callback prop, allowing them to make the change if and when desired

```ts
type EntityMeta = MetaData & { entity: Entity };

interface ListProps {
  row?: (entity: Entity) => JSX.Element,
  rowWithMeta?: (row: EntityMeta) => JSX.Element,
}
```

In your `List` component, you can then make the decision on which renderer to use

```jsx
const rowRenderer = useCallback(
  (row: EntityMeta) => props.rowWithMeta?.(row) ?? props.row?.(row.entity),
  [props.rowWithMeta, props.row]
);

return (
  <table>
    {rows.map((row, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>{rowRenderer(row)}</tr>
    ))}
  </table>
);
```

---

Personally, the issues you noted regarding point #2 above would not concern me. I would simply construct whatever meta-data you want and pass that as a second parameter

```ts
row: (entity: Entity, meta: MetaData)
```

You can treat that second parameter however you want, just leave the first as purely the *entity*

```jsx
return (
  <table>
    {rows.map(({ entity, ...meta }, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>{props.row(entity, meta)}</tr>
    ))}
  </table>
);
```